# Tensorflow object detection with 16bit images

Tags: python, tensorflow, 16-bit, object-detection-api

I want to use tensorflow's object detection api with 16 bit satellite-images.

I created a tfrecord file with 16bit pngs
than using the `train.py` from object detection the images are converted to 8bit.

So I changed in tensorflow/python/ops following files
`gen_image_ops.py` in the function `decode_png()` the `dytpe` to `uint16`
`image_ops.impl.py` the function `decode_image` to just return `_png()`
this seems to work

but i want to ask if there is a smarter way to use 16bit images
thanks for help

Comment: Hi! So have you finally managed the issue? I am facing the similar task right now, but with Computered Tomography images (.dicom files).